# Evaluating delay for Xbee

Tags: arduino-uno, communication, xbee

I will explain my task in a simplified way. I'm communicating among 3 Xbee's.

The attached code is for the sender Xbee. This Xbee actually sends multiple values of **value1** (*here for simplification I assigned it to constant value 10*). For finding the value1 it does some other calculations as well and then assigns it.

But I find that if I reduce or remove the delay(100) I end up receiving improper values. I guess delay gives a buffer time for data transmission but my question is how to do I calculate the minimum delay or how can justify that this is the delay needed ?

I hope you can understand my question. If not please comment I will give some more pertinent details.

```
  // Sender Xbee
    void setup()
    {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    }
    void loop()
    {
    int value1 = 10; // some hardcoded values to send
    Serial.print('H'); // unique header to identify start of message
    Serial.print(value1,DEC);
    Serial.print(","); // note that a comma is sent after the last field
    Serial.print('\n'); // send a cr/lf
    delay(100);
    }
```

Comment: If timing is critical (and assuming you do not want to loose any message), you probably need some notification back that the message has been received correctly (possibly with a checksum value).

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience with Xbee, I would say the limit is 50ms as Xbee can do the lowest sampling rate of 50ms.